# CodeIgniter how to make a session to close on user browser close

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have disabled "destryo_on_close" in codeIgniter session configuration.

I do not need it very much but for one instance.

I have put "remember me" checkbox for the user login.

As usual, when user logs in I set sessions to keep him logged in. But, if the user uncheck remember me, I have to make $this->session->userdata('email') to be destroyed on user browser close event. CodeIgniter has this option generally for all sessions which I do not want and only need it in the case user unchecks 'remember me' and only for 'email' session.

Comment: I'm not sure if it possible to have diffrent configs for an individuel like that, but you should really be using cookies for this.

Comment: Sessions only live for the browser session, so when the browser is closed the session is destroyed. It’s cookies that persist, even after the browser has been closed.

Comment: No! CodeIgniter uses cookies for sessioning and that's why it gives you the ability to hold them as long as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I undertand, but how about unsetting the data you need? take a look [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) on Removing Session Data

**EDIT**: I don't know how your code structure is, but maybe something like this would work:

```
if($this->input->post('remember_me') == 1){
    // user has clicked 'remember me'
    // your code here ... 
} else {
    // user has not clicked remember me
    $this->config->set_item('sess_expire_on_close', true);
}
```

I haven't tested though to see if it works, but if you read [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html), you can set or change the config values as you need.

Comment: yes good. But to complete what you said, I need to set a 'is_permanent' as a boolean to check whether the user has checked remember_me or not. Thanks for that.